# Sending data through NFC continously without Beam UI every time

Tags: android, nfc, nfc-p2p, android-beam

How can I send data between two devices using NFC continuously without getting the Beam UI every time in Android?

Comment: What do you mean by continuously ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to transfer NFC data from one Android device to another without the 'Touch to Beam' screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23085990/is-it-possible-to-transfer-nfc-data-from-one-android-device-to-another-without-t)

Answer (score 0):

The UI is intended and unavoidable. Poses a large security risk otherwise.