# Is it possible to transfer NFC files from one Android device to another without the 'Touch to Beam' screen?

Tags: android, xamarin, nfc, apdu, hce

Following this question I found the way to transmit messages without using the Beam UI

> [Is it possible to transfer NFC data from one Android device to another without the 'Touch to Beam' screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23085990/is-it-possible-to-transfer-nfc-data-from-one-android-device-to-another-without-t?rq=1)

This is the answer I wanted:

> Only starting with Android 4.4, there is the possibility to communicate between two Android devices over NFC without the Beam UI (actually without using Android Beam and peer-to-peer mode at all): If both devices are 4.4+, one device can use Android HCE to emulate a contactless smartcard and one device can use the reader-mode API (this only works with the reader-mode API introduced in 4.4, so both devices need to be 4.4+) to communicate with the emulated smartcard.

However I would like to transfer whole files, is it possible to do it? I haven't been able to do it between a 5.1 and a 7.0 devices using the CardReader and CardEmulation samples in https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples.

If I try to send large data (such as all the bytes from a file) they never connect. However, with small messages (such as the original number in the sample) it can be done but not without a lot of transreceive exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You can, of course, exchange larger amounts of data (such as whole files) through NFC card emulation. Since NFC is rather slow, it might not be your best choice to transfer the file over NFC directly though.

#### Use NFC for data transfer

In card emulation mode, you <strike>need to</strike> *should* use APDUs (cf. ISO/IEC 7816-4) to communicate between the reader app and the HCE app. On most devices, APDUs are limited to their short form, which means that you only have up to 255 data bytes (+ 4 header bytes + max. 2 bytes length information) for each request that you send from the reader to the HCE app and up to 256 bytes (+ 2 status bytes) for responses from the HCE app to the reader.

Consequently, you need to split the file into smaller chunks that can be packed into  APDUs. You might want to consider creating a simple protocol that allows you to request specific chunks (identified by offset and length) of the file. For instance, you could send a command APDU like this to request one chunk of the file:

```
80 10 XX YY  ZZ
```

`XX YY` is a two-byte offset in the file and `ZZ` is the one-byte length.

In resonse you the HCE app could answer with the response APDU:

```
<DATA>  90 00
```

`90 00` is a status word indicating successful execution of the command.

#### Use NFC to establish an out-of-band channel

Since NFC is rather slow and not well-suited for exchanging large amounts of data, you might want to use NFC only to establish an initial connection. You could then exchange credentials for a Bluetooth or Wi-Fi connection to use for transfering the actual data file.